# missing ')' before 'constant'

Tags: c++-cli

I am very much a beginner at C++ and have done very little coding in this before.

I keep receiving these build errors on every build. I can manage to get rid of the syntax errors but it is error C2661 that is giving me all the trouble.

I receive all these errors on the one line:  "OpenGL = gcnew Create_OpenGL(this, 10, 10, 640 480);"

here is the code im working with.

```
public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    private: OpenGLForm::Create_OpenGL ^OpenGL; // #2 pointer to OpenGL
    public:
        Form1(void)
        {

        InitializeComponent();

        -------> OpenGL = gcnew Create_OpenGL(this, 10, 10, 640 480);<------

        }
```

Here is the output from the build:

```
1>  OpenGl_3D.cpp
1>c:\users\shane carroll\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\opengl_3d\opengl_3d\Form1.h(29): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'constant'
1>c:\users\shane carroll\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\opengl_3d\opengl_3d\Form1.h(29): error C2661: 'OpenGLForm::Create_OpenGL::Create_OpenGL' : no overloaded function takes 4 arguments
1>c:\users\shane carroll\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\opengl_3d\opengl_3d\Form1.h(29): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'constant'
1>c:\users\shane carroll\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\opengl_3d\opengl_3d\Form1.h(29): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
```

Any help on this topic would be greatly appreciated. Again im very new to this.

Comment: I'm no OGL expert, but I would wager you aren't supposed to create a `Create_OpenGL` object nameed `OpenGL`.  I think you're supposed to make an `OpenGL` object named `OGLInstance` via the function `Create_OpenGL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There certainly is an error with "missing *something* before constant".  Take a very close look at the line, right here:

```
640 480
```

Putting numbers next to each other separated by a space is meaningless. The compiler has NO CLUE whether you meant `640+480` or `640*480` or `"640 480"` or `640, 480`.

Since you have an unmatched parenthesis, the error-message generator guesses you might have meant `640); 480`... and generates the messages for "missing `)`" and "missing `;`"